# Make 3D polygon from Point Z in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I am trying to create a Convex Hull or ConcaveHull as a polygon Z from a set of points Z which I am grouping by id. 
I tried to use ST_ConvexHull but it's returning Polygon in 2D, not in 3D.

My inputs point are LiDAR representation of tree canopies and I would like to combine them into a single canopy with Polygon Z geometry type.

The pseudo query should look something like:

```
 SELECT  st_3dconvexhull(st_collect(geom)) FROM points_z 
 GROUP BY canopy_id;
```

Comment: Creating a non-planar (higher dimensional) Convex Hull is a *very* intense operation, computatiinally, even if shell faces are already given. I doubt that PostgreSQL/PostGIS is the right place to store and analyze high density point clouds, despite the best efforts to allow for it (pgpointcloud).

Comment: Even if I got around 200 points per polygon is it still a very intensive operation to create it? Maybe you know in pure math how to do it... then I could try to translate it to Postgres query.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue is described in the [postgis mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2017-March/041959.html). Even though ST_CONVEXHULL supports 3d geometries, it doesn't use the third axis for calculations.

You could use the [Quickhall Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull) to generate convex hulls for 3d geometries. This algorithm also has an implementation in cgal, so could create a simple wrapper in postgis that uses [the convex_hull_3 function](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/index.html).